# GObject.idle_add(), thread.join() and my program hangs

Tags: python, multithreading, gobject

I've a problem: **my main thread should start and join a thread that has a to run about 10-15 seconds.**

So:

- my **main thread starts a child thread**, whom has to run about 10-15 seconds
- my **main thread joins the child thread**: the main thread needs the result of the child thread
- **in the meanwhile the child thread runs, i've to update the GUI**, it is just a progressbar (possibly every 0.2 second)
- updating the GUI: i'll use a **recursive function**
- the child thread finishes and the main thread gets the result

The problem with my code is that the ***Trovarete_Window appears and starts to be updated only when the worker function has already ended***. So my program hangs/freezes until the worker runs.

Here is my code:

```
def collega_GUI(widget, args=()):

    builder.get_object('Trovarete_Window').show_all()
    progressbar.set_pulse_step(0.20)

    pulse()
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    print 'a'


def pulse():

    if not event.is_set():
        progressbar.pulse()
        GObject.timeout_add(300, pulse)


def worker():
    #hard work
```

Comment: Where is `collega_GUI` called? Where is the main loop started?

Comment: Also, what is it that you need from `worker` that requires the main thread to block until its done? How is your real program actually getting the result from the worker thread?

Comment: 1) collega_gui is called from a Gtk.Button. 2) When the child thread reaches the end, then it sets a variable with the result. The variable is returned by a function, called after the join().

Comment: Indded.  That is usually what happens when calling join() in a GUI event handler.  Don't wait in a GUI event handler.  Don't make calls that block, don't sleep and don't call join().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `t.join()` inside `collegea_GUI`. Calling `t.join()` means your main thread - the thread that's running the event loop - is blocked until `worker` completes. As long as you're blocked inside `collegea_GUI`, your main loop cannot run, which means the call to `pulse` you scheduled can't run, and the GUI can't be updated.

Instead of calling `t.join()`, you'll need to do something similar to what you're doing with `pulse` - schedule a function to run that does a non-blocking check to see if `worker` is finished. Something like this:

```
def collega_GUI(widget, args=()):

    builder.get_object('Trovarete_Window').show_all()
    progressbar.set_pulse_step(0.20)

    pulse()
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    wait_for_t(t)

def wait_for_t(t):
   if not t.is_alive():
       t.join() # This won't block, since the thread isn't alive anymore
       print 'a'
       # Do whatever else you would do when join() (or maybe collega_GUI?) returns
   else:
       Gobject.timeout_add(200, wait_for_t, t)
```

Comment: It's ok, thanks for the reply, but there is one problem: i can't put the rest of the code inside wait_for_t. collega_GUI is my main thread, it has all the data structures. I'll try to answer, although i still have a minor problem (I think)