# Any alternative of thread.join() to update wxPython GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have written a program, that loops through some given files (movie files actually), searches for subtitle for that file, and downloads it. It's a wxPython GUI application. Now, each time a subtitle is downloaded, I want to update the ListControl of the GUI with some text. The code is below:

```python
for i in range(total_items):
    path = self.list.GetItem(i, 0) # gets the item (first column) from list control
    path = path.GetText() # contains the path of the movie file

    t = Thread(target = self.Downloader, args = (path,))
    t.start()

    t.join() # using this hangs the GUI and it can't be updated
    self.list.SetItem(i, 1, 'OK') # update the listcontrol for each download
```

It is obvious that I want to update the GUI only when the thread finishes. I used t.join(), but later understood that it cannot be used to update GUI's, as stated in this question: [GObject.idle_add(), thread.join() and my program hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172107/gobject-idle-add-thread-join-and-my-program-hangs)

Now, I want to use something similar as stated in that question, but I can't figure anything out as I am using wxPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use `wx.CallAfter` from inside your thread, which will use the main thread to call whatever you pass it

```
def Downloader(a_listbox,item_index):
    path = a_listbox.GetItem(item_index, 0) # gets the item (first column) from list control
    path = path.GetText() # contains the path of the movie file
    # do some work with the path and do your download
    wx.CallAfter(a_listbox.SetItem, i, 1, 'OK') # update the listcontrol for each download (wx.CallAfter will force the call to be made in the main thread)

...
for i in range(total_items):    
    t = Thread(target = self.Downloader, args = (self.list,i,))
    t.start()
```

based on your clarification below (you still should use wx.CallAfter)

```
def Downloader(self):
    for item_index in range(total_items):
      path = self.list.GetItem(item_index, 0) # gets the item (first column) from list control
      path = path.GetText() # contains the path of the movie file
      # do some work with the path and do your download
      wx.CallAfter(self.list.SetItem, i, 1, 'OK') # update the listcontrol for 

Thread(target=self.Downloader).start()
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this won't work in my case. My program uses "xmlrpc" request using an API key, and only one request can be made at a time from a single user account. But your provided code runs multiple request at once, thus generating an error. It seems like, I have to find out a way to run the threads one after another, instead of running all of them at once.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually, I am new to threading, sorry for not getting the point.

Comment: @SadmanMuhibSamyo Just a query. If you can only download one file at a time, why are you threading the download? Is your code doing something else at the same time?

Comment: 1. The UI stops responding till all the downloads are complete
2. I can&#39;t update the UI till all downloads are complete @rolf